# How to add the date timestamp to log4j2 logfiles?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I want to create day dependent logfiles with `log4j2`:

```
<RollingFile name="APP" fileName="application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" />
```

Resulting logfile name: `application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log`, the timestamp is not replaced. Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pattern should not be given in the attribute "fileName" rather you have to specify the pattern in the attribute "filePattern" as like below.

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${log-path}/filename.log" 
filePattern="${log-path}/filename-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" >
...
...
</RollingFile>
```

The "%i" is the counter that will be automatically incremented in rollover.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: this does not add a filename with todays date in the current log file

Answer (score 34):

To append the filename with date, replace %d with below format, i was having the same problem and but got by doing so :

```
<RollingFile name="APP" fileName="application-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log" />
```

Comment: It is overwriting old logs with chunk of current date logs. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432150/log4j2-overwrites-past-day-log-file

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">

    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">D:/logs/</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>

        <RollingFile name="DebuggerLogger" fileName="${log-path}CMSAutomation.${date:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss}.log" filePattern="${log-path}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="ALL">
            <AppenderRef ref="DebuggerLogger"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Comment: You'll want to use `${date:yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}` for 24 hour time. Other 5am and 5pm both appear as 05.

Answer (score 1):

In yaml check the Property `filePattern` defined as `"${date:yyyy-MM-dd}"`, which helps to tag the date. If you are interested to tag the `HOSTNAME` environment variable to date then : `"${env:HOST}-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}"`

```
Properties:
    Property:
      - name: log-path
        value: "logs"
      - name:  filePattern
        value: "${date:yyyy-MM-dd}"

  Appenders:

    Console:
      name: Console_Appender
      target: SYSTEM_OUT
      PatternLayout:
        pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"

    File:
      name: File_Appender
      fileName: "${log-path}/filelog-${filePattern}.log"

      PatternLayout:
        pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"

    RollingFile:
      - name: RollingFile_Appender
        fileName: "${log-path}/rollingfile-${filePattern}.log"
        filePattern: "logs/archive/rollingfile.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm}.gz"
        PatternLayout:
          pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"
```

Answer (score 1):

To show the date with the time timestamp to log4j2 file then add in log4j2.property file like:
`appender.file.fileName=${filename}/app-${date:yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss}.log`

Answer (score 0):

Use `ASizeBasedTriggeringPolicy` class in appender.
You can even append the current second to the logfile name. `%d{yyyy_MM_dd HH.mm.ss}`

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.*;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginAttribute;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginFactory;

@Plugin(name = "ASizeBasedTriggeringPolicy",
        category = "Core",
        printObject = true
)
public class ASizeBasedTriggeringPolicy extends AbstractTriggeringPolicy {
    private SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy sizeBasedTriggeringPolicy;
    private RollingFileManager aManager;

    protected ASizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(String maxFileSize) {
        sizeBasedTriggeringPolicy = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy(maxFileSize);

    }

    public void initialize(RollingFileManager aManager) {
        sizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.initialize(aManager);
        this.aManager = aManager;
    }

    public boolean isTriggeringEvent(LogEvent event) {
        if (sizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.isTriggeringEvent(event)) {
            aManager.getPatternProcessor().setPrevFileTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @PluginFactory
    public static ASizeBasedTriggeringPolicy createPolicy(@PluginAttribute("size") String size) {
        return new ASizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size);
    }
}
```

Then use `ASizeBasedTriggeringPolicy` in log appender

```
<RollingFile name="complete-log" fileName="${log-path}/complete-${date:yyyy_MM_dd HH.mm.ss} .log" 
                 filePattern="${log-path}/app-complete-%d{yyyy_MM_dd HH.mm.ss} - %i.log" >
    ...
    ... 
    <Policies>
         <ASizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="200 kB"  />
    </Policies>
</RollingFile>
```