# Log4j2 overwrites past day log file

Tags: java, log4j2, pattern-layout

I'm using Log4j2 ver 2.3

log4j2.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile"
                 fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/catalina.${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
                 filePattern="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/catalina.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[TID=%X{TId}] %d{MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %c %M:%L %p: %m%n"/>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy modulate="true" />
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="DEBUG" >
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

All works fine until next day when log from a previous day is getting overwritten by some logs from current day.

Example:
catalina.2018-03-21.log yesterday (March 21st) was fine but today got overwritten by some logs from 2018-03-22 when catalina.2018-03-22.log contains rest of logs from today (March 22nd)

Any thoughts?

Comment: do you have more than one app writing to the same log file?

Comment: @FranMontero yes, I have other modules which uses JDK14Logger which saves to the same file. All was fine till switching Log4j to Log4j2

Comment: @FranMontero maybe simple I don't need `RollingFile` as current date is appended to the log filename anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log4j 2.3 is somewhat old, being released on 2015-05-09, almost 3 years old. So try using a updated version; version 2.11.0 is the latest as of now which was released on 2018-03-11.

**Update:** To continue using Log4j 2.3, you can *compromise your requirements*. One of the options could be using static value for `fileName` attribute. E.g. `.../catalina.log`, `.../catalina.current.log`, etc.

Comment: I need to use because of JDK6

Comment: @JackTheKnife Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
BasicConfigurator.resetConfiguration()
```

in the method that uses logger after *BasicConfigurator.configure()*

Comment: I don't have `BasicConfigurator.configure()` in my code

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an auto-increment variable to your file pattern (%i).
This worked fine for me.

```
filePattern="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/catalina.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log"
```

Answer (score 0):

mention in time based TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy time interval as **1** it will rollover file on daylly basis