# Log4j2 saves to an old dated log file

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

My log4j2.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
<Appenders>
    <File name="CatalinaLog" fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/catalina.${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[TID=%X{TId}] %d{MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %c %M:%L %p: %m%n"/>
    </File>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="DEBUG" >
        <AppenderRef ref="CatalinaLog" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

It works fine till next day when logs are added to previous dated log not the current dated log until Tomcat restart.

Example:
yesterday was March 22 2018
today is March 23 2018

logs are still saved to catalina.2018-03-22.log instead of catalina.2018-03-23.log till Tomcat restart.

Any thoughts on that?

Comment: you mean the default way of working to avoid log files getting to large?

Comment: @Stultuske No - I have updated OP with an example

Comment: Are you missing `DailyRollingFileAppender` in your properties file?

Comment: @notyou I had `RollingFile` appender before and ended up with other issue described in that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432150/log4j2-overwrites-past-day-log-file